# CUPS SERVER ERROR

Tags: networking, printing, epson, virtual-printer

While trying to connect EPSON M3170 Printer which is connected in network shows CUPS server error

THERE WAS AN ERROR DURING CUPS OPERATION.'SUCCESS'.

[image]

Comment: Generally it is better include the image in the question

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is your version of `cups-filters`? (Do `apt policy cups-filters` and look under "Installed"). Your problem sounds like this one: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1933848